# C#: How to implement a thin wrapper, with a read only interface

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am trying to create a unique ID class (`UID`) to identify a series of objects, as a thin wrapper around `int`. It needs to implement a read-only interface (`IReadOnlyUID`) which, when used, would prevent the inner `int` from being rewritten.

---

*Details:*

In my code I deal with many objects, let's call them `Entity`, that have a read-only interface, let's say `IReadOnlyEntity`. This is important because I occasionally need to serve `Entity` data while protecting its integrity (but not always - at other times it needs to be writable). Like so:

```
public class Entity : IReadOnlyEntity
{
    int Example {get; set;}
    List<int> Example2 {get; set;}
        IReadOnlyList<int> IReadOnlyEntity.Example2 => Example2;
}
public interface IReadOnlyEntity {
    int Example {get;}
    IReadOnlyList<int> Example2 {get;}
}
```

They are each identified by a unique ID, so I'm trying to create a thin wrapper around an `int`, let's say `UID`, to be able to identify each `Entity`.

```
public class UID
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public UID() { }
    public UID(int value) { Value = value; }
    public static implicit operator UID(int x) { return new UID(x); }
    public static implicit operator int(UID x) { return x.Value; }
    public override string ToString() { return string.Format( "UID({0})", Value );
}
```

The problem, of course, is that `UID` is rewritable. If I serve it as part of `IReadOnlyEntity` (e.g. if I had a member `UID TheUIDofSomeOtherEntityITrust`), then `UID.Value` could be rewritten externally.

`int` itself is passed by value and doesn't have this issue, but as I understand it, `UID` is passed by reference and therefore would.

I tried to create an `IReadOnlyUID` interface, but this blocks casts. So the following code doesn't work, because "user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed":

```
interface IReadOnlyUID
{
    int Value {get;}
    static implicit operator int(IReadOnlyUID x) { return x.Value; }
}
```

Is there a way to implement the above, or is there a better way to give the Entity objects a unique ID?

Comment: ... in dot net there are classes like `ImmutableArray` or `ReadonlyArray` however these only exists for collections for a reason, if you want immutable or readonly classes/structs you should try [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), wich also enable you to create copies with changed values easier

Comment: Why is `UID.Value` writable in the first place? if it's made `readonly` or `init` the problem disappears. In fact an extremely short way of writing it would be `record UID(int Value) { /* conversion operators */ }`. (In C# 10 I'd make it a `readonly record struct`.) Do note that a wrapper like this with implicit conversion both ways is of limited value (or possibly none) due to the compiler's eagerness to apply the conversions; while you won' t be able to mix different IDs directly, some unexpected mixups can still occur whenever an `int` gets involved.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's a really good point, it doesn't need to be writeable after initialisation. I don't think I can use `record`s (as the code base is pre-C# 9.0), but is there another short idiom you'd recommend for this purpose?

Comment: `int Value { get; private set; }` would be enough to make the value immutable to outsiders.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Wait - I'm just thinking now, and does making `UID.Value` readonly really resolve the problem? If `Entity` has a member `UID id;`, and `Entity` is accessed through a `IReadOnlyEntity` interface, is `id` itself still not hot-swappable for another (new) `UID`?

Comment: Of course, if you have a writable `UID` property that's effectively the same thing as a writable `int` property. The only thing `UID` gives you is the ability to not (say) accidentally use a `UID` as a `SomeDifferentID`. Immutability has to go all the way -- there's a reason records were added to make supporting it simpler, since it's quite painful to implement in C#. All that said -- if you have an `IReadOnlyEntity` that offers a read-only property of type `UID`, an external client could *not* change it if `UID` itself is immutable.

Comment: And note that in all this, of course, the best you get from immutability is a way to not *accidentally* do it wrong. It would always be possible for a client to hard-cast an `IReadOnlyEntity` to an `Entity` and access the mutable properties that way, it would just be very hard to do so accidentally. This is why the cost/benefit ratio of making things immutable also has to be considered.

Comment: I understand, that's useful advice. I momentarily blanked on how I implemented `id` in `Entity` / `IReadOnlyEntity`. It should be passed through immutably in case of the latter. Those are important points re immutability, and you've picked up astutely on what I'm trying to do - `IReadOnlyEntity` does in fact exist to prevent accidents, and there are different kinds of IDs needed, hence the wrapper. Good advice! Happy to accept your suggestions as an answer if you post one.